# How to install libraries for a program?

Tags: python

I am making a game that use some 3rd party libraries and I want to know how can I make a setup to automatly install this requeriments or something like that (I don't know how this is called).

My program needs this libraries: Tabulate 0.7.7 and Progress 1.2.

How can I auto-install them and how can I auto-uninstall when I don't want to use my program anymore?

I don't have any like licence, setup, info, requeriments or something like that files... (but my program have several packages)

**PD:** I use python 3.6 32-bits win 10 64-bits.

**PD2:** My program structure is: (I don't know if it's necesary but...)

```
Heroes Quest
|---Heroes_Quest.py    # Main file
|---core
|   |---__init__.py
|   |---registration.py
|---functions
|   |---__init__.py
|   |---basic.py
|   |---metabolism.py
|   |---tmp.py
|---menu
|   |---__init__.py
|   |---menu.py
|   |---profile.py
|   |---rest.py
|   |---train.py
|---variables
    |---__init__.py
    |---config.py
    |---trainings.py
    |---variables.py
```

Answer (score 1):

To manage Python packages you can simply use `pip`. To install Tabulate for example you can open the Command Prompt or Terminal and type in `pip install tabulate`. For Progress 1.3 you can download the sources files [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/progress) and then navigate to that folder and execute `python setup.py install`.

That being said if your target computer does not have these libraries needed to run the program you can install them via `install_requires` in `setup.py`. For more information, I would suggest you read [this Python document.](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#installing-setuptools)

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Typically Python packages and all requirements are installed/distributed using `setuptools` and `distutils` by configuring a `setup.py` file.

I would recommend to check out this quickstart tutorial:

http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Also here is a great article about the python packages distribution:

https://tom-christie.github.io/articles/pypi/